# segfault using SWIG converted code for tcl

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, tcl, swig

I'm having a segmentation fault with my program.

In fact I write a library in C++ and convert it for tcl using SWIG.

The segfault occurs here:

```
return Tcl_NewIntObj(static_cast< int >(value));
```

where value=0

the gdb back trace shows:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000054b6 in ?? ()
#1  0xb6650d5d in SWIG_From_long (value=0) at mntdisplay_wrap.cc:1712
#2  SWIG_From_int (value=0) at mntdisplay_wrap.cc:1722
#3  Testguimnt_Init (interp=0x9714e28) at mntdisplay_wrap.cc:3774
#4  0xb76748fe in Tcl_LoadObjCmd () from /opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so
#5  0xb75d02af in TclNREvalObjv () from /opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so
#6  0xb75d0859 in Tcl_EvalObjv () from /opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so
#7  0xb75d0d99 in TclEvalEx () from /opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so
#8  0xb7670045 in Tcl_FSEvalFileEx () from /opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so
#9  0xb767645f in Tcl_MainEx () from /opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib/libtcl8.6.so
#10 0x0804885c in main ()
```

In the wrapper:
line 1712:

```
SWIGINTERNINLINE Tcl_Obj* 
SWIG_From_long  (long value)
{
  if (((long) INT_MIN <= value) && (value <= (long) INT_MAX)) {
    return Tcl_NewIntObj(static_cast< int >(value));  //1712
  } else {
    return Tcl_NewLongObj(value);
  }
}
```

1722:

```
SWIGINTERNINLINE Tcl_Obj *
SWIG_From_int  (int value)
{    
  return SWIG_From_long  (value); //1722
}
```

3774:

```
SWIG_Tcl_SetConstantObj(interp, "MESSAGE_NEW", SWIG_From_int(static_cast< int >(MESSAGE_NEW)));
```

where MESSAGE_NEW is defined in a enum and is 0.

Please, if you have any idea, please help me. Thank you!

EDIT:

I found the cause of the problem: it's an linking error.

I created a new thread for this issue:

[C++: linked library disappears and gives segfault during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379452/c-linked-library-disappears-and-gives-segfault-during-execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

Please see my other post:
[C++: linked library disappears and gives segfault during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379452/c-linked-library-disappears-and-gives-segfault-during-execution/18380228#18380228)

There was an undefined symbol of my library. I defined it and problem solved!

The confusion was, my program crashed in the middle of tcl wrapper functions (where my undefined symbol was not involved at all). I don't really know why but that's it..

Hope it will help others!